# Remove any special character from a second Regex group

Tags: javascript, regex

I' trying to replace a "X" character from a string but only if it occurs after the last comma. Let's give an example:

```
josè ignacio fazio,ARG,62.30X 1 55.08X 1 117.38 1 13.72 3
juan gutiérrez,ARG,72.04X 2 58.81 X 3 130.85 2 13.80 4
```

Currently, I was trying things like that:

```
content.replace(/(.*,(?!.*,))((?!X).*)/gim, "$1,$2)
```

The first group `(.*,(?!.*,))`  is used to capture all text to the last comma and results in

```
josè ignacio fazio,ARG,
```

Now I'm trying to remove all "X" from the second group

```
62.30X 1 55.08X 1 117.38 1 13.72 3
```

Unfortunatly it wont work and so I'm asking for help please.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a replacer function to process your 2nd capture group:

```js
const s = 'juan gutiérrez,ARG,72.04X 2 58.81 X 3 130.85 2 13.80 4';

var r = s.replace(/(.*,)(.+)/, (_, g1, g2) => 
        g1 + g2.replace(/X/g, ''), s);

console.log(r);
//=> "juan gutiérrez,ARG,72.04 2 58.81  3 130.85 2 13.80 4"
```

Also a note on your pattern `(.*,(?!.*,))`: you don't need to use a negative lookahead to make sure that you have matched last comma. Just `.*,` is enough to ensure that.

Comment: Thx, but isn't something like that impossible to do with a single regex, too? There is a ruleset (list of regex) stored in my database to process various data. That's why I'm unable (unfortunately) to handle this as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

If a [lookbehind is supported](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind) you could use:

```
(?<=,[^,\n]*)X(?=[^,\n]*$)
```

- `(?<=,[^,\n]*)` Positive lookbehind asser `,` to the left followed by optional chars other than `,`
- `X` Match literaly
- `(?=[^,\n]*$)` Positive lookahead, assert no more comma's to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3nbN1a/1)

```js
const regex = /(?<=,[^,\n]*)X(?=[^,\n]*$)/gm;
const str = `josè ignacio fazio,ARG,62.30X 1 55.08X 1 117.38 1 13.72 3
juan gutiérrez,ARG,72.04X 2 58.81 X 3 130.85 2 13.80 4
juan X gutiérrez,ARG,72.04X 2 58.81 X 3 130.85, X 2 13.80 4`;

console.log(str.replace(regex, ""));
```

Comment: Good use of variable length lookbehind

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is no comma after `X` and remove them:

```js
s.replace(/X(?=[^,]*$)/g, '')
```

If you have to check for a comma in the sentence:

```js
s.replace(/(?<=,[^,]*)X(?=[^,]*$)/g, '')
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/gOgMFh/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  X                        'X'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^,]*                    any character except: ',' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

And

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ,                        ','
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^,]*                    any character except: ',' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
```